# How to make an ajax call in MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4. I have to create a login name validation. After writing a string, when we exit from the textbox, it should display whether it is available or not.

The View Code is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            @Html.TextBox("textbox1")
            @Html.TextBox("txtTest")
        </div>
    </section>
}
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#textbox1').blur(function(){
                alert("a");
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Now in place of `alert("a")`, I will have to call an action. That action will contains the database check.

Controller Code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
        public ActionResult SearchUser()
        {
            string ExistsCheck;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"].ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UserName_Exist_tbl_UserDetails", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Request.Form["textbox1"]);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().ToLower() == "exists")
            {
                ExistsCheck = "Exists";
            }
            else
            {
                ExistsCheck = "Available";
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Now my question is how to call this `SearchUser()` action and display it into the same page  when we go out from the textbox1.

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("textbox1")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="regTitle"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        @Html.TextBox("txtTest")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </section>
}
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textbox1').blur(function () {
            var params = { userName: $(this).val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/SearchUser",
                type: "get",
                data: { userName: $("#textbox1").val() },
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (response.IsExisting) {
                        // User name is existing already, you can display a message to the user
                        $("#regTitle").html("Already Exists")
                    }
                    else {
                        // User name is not existing
                        $("#regTitle").html("Available")
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                // callback handler that will be called on completion
                // which means, either on success or error
                complete: function () {
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

**Controller method**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mvc4_Ajax.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SearchUser(string userName)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"].ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UserName_Exist_tbl_UserDetails", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            var isExisting = dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().ToLower() == "exists";
            return Json(new { IsExisting = isExisting }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
        }
    }
}
```

- I would recommend using an ORM (Entity Framework or Nhibernate)
- Beware SQL injection even if you're using a stored procedure:
  http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/12/stored-procedures-and-orms-wont-save.html

Comment: The ajax is firing for the first time when loading the view. Next time the ajax is not firing.

Comment: My JavaScript code is supposed to replace only `alert("a");` you should keep everything else.

Comment: Yes, I used it in the same section.

Comment: You shouldn't use `complete` in your case. `complete` will be executed in all the cases (success and error).

Comment: Yes, it is always going into the else section of complete

Comment: So, is there any other way as it is not coming into the success section.

Comment: In this case it means there is an error, you should use Firebug to have a look at the HTTP response.

Comment: The issue is related to security. Now I changed it to: return Json(new JsonResult { Data = new { IsExisting = isExisting } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); but the problem is still it is displaying Available always.

Comment: Got it. return Json(new { IsExisting = isExisting }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); , I updated your solution again.

Comment: If you don't put the [HttpGet] attribute on the Action you will get a 405 server result code.

Answer (score 2):

You are reinventing the wheel.  MVC provides an interface - [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) - that accomplishes just this.  Almost all MVC form validation can be accomplished with a combination of property attributes (i.e. [Required] server-side and client-side with Unobtrusive Validation), IClientValidatable (client-side) and IValidatable (server-side). Here's a complete validation example - [MVC3 - Custom Client-Side Validation with Unobtrusive Ajax - a Complete Example](http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2012/04/21/MVC3-Custom-Client-Side-Validation-with-Unobtrusive-Ajax.aspx)

Comment: Validation is only one example of when you would use AJAX.  This is a great question and great answer, very useful.